# zlib.output_compression and output_buffering

Tags: php, compression, buffer

Can I compress output by setting the `zlib.output_compression` directive to `on`, and then set the `output_buffering` directive to `off`?

Secondly I read that I can set a number value to the `zlib.output_compression` directive which specifies a specific buffer size.
But what if I also set the `output_buffering` directive to a different number value of bytes? What will be the max buffer size?

Comment: another question: is the zlib.output_compression_level referes also to the compression level of the ob_gzhandler() function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes, you can compress PHP output this way, but web-servers (nginx, Apache) can do such  compressing more effective for all type of content (css assets, etc), not only PHP output :)
   http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html
2. Yes, you can set zlib.output_compression to numeric value
   http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression

> This option also accepts integer values instead of boolean "On"/"Off",
> using this you can set the output buffer size (default is 4KB).
> As for max buffer size, you cant set it more than web-server can handle. For example, nginx use 4K or 8K output buffer.
> http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffer_size

3. ob_gzhandler compression level use zlib.output_compression_level, which is -1 per default, level 6 (The default value, -1, lets the server decide which level to use).
   But! PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php said:

> You cannot use both ob_gzhandler() and zlib.output_compression. Also
> note that using zlib.output_compression is preferred over
> ob_gzhandler().

Comment: what will be the buffer size, if I set the output_buffering directive to 5000 and set the zlib.output_compression to 4000?

Comment: with set zlib.output_compression to numeric value you also set output buffering value, so output buffer will be 4000

Comment: I wonder how `lets the server decide which level to use` works. Decides how? Upon of some parameter, available memory, number of processes, string size or what else?

Comment: See gzip_comp_level variable: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_comp_level